# Controller returning 404 - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, controller

[image]verifyAuth checks for JWT expiry

```
    router.get("/profile" ,verifyAuth, superProfile)
```

```
    /////Database Models
    import Superadmin from "../../models/superadmin"


    /////GET Superadmin Profile
    const superProfile = async(req,res,next)=>{
    const {_id} = req.userData

    try {

        var data = await Superadmin.findOne({_id },{
            password : 0,
            jwt : 0
        })
       

        res.status(200).send(data)
        
    } catch (error) {

        return res.status(400).send("Error")
        
    }
        

    }


    export {superProfile}
```

After verifyAuth passed the control to superProfile, it responds as 404. But , if i remove the verifyAuth, the route is working

Comment: This is my first time using the controller , and using babel-node in node js. I am confused in setting the controller pattern. It's returning 404, when passed to superProfile

Comment: Do you need to call next() after your findOne() method? I dont' see your next() call anywhere.

Comment: Where is the code for "verifyAuth" ?

Comment: i have attached a image for verifyAuth @DeekshithHegde

Comment: i have added a image for verifyAuth, please check that too.@Jordan

Answer (score 0):

This problem got solved. I used **module.exports** instead of **export default** in verifyAuth. I don't know what was actually wrong, anyway Thank you guys